# how to add input into inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Sorry if this is a little confusing, First time using this site so I dont know if I entered my code in right or not. So my question is, when I run this program in class driver I get this:

```
name: No Name Yet
Manufacturer: no name yet
Engine Cyclinders: 0
Load: 0.0
Towing: 0.0
```

Which is the default, now I am trying to be able to put a input in the class driver that will change say the name to whatever I set it as from class `Person` for example. I have tried doing `p.setName("Tim")` but it will only show the name as `tim` if I call the `writeouput` method from class `Person`. If I call the `writeoutput` from class Truck then it says no name yet. I put super in the `writeoutput` but I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. any help would be appreciated

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person()
    {
        name = "No Name Yet";
    }
    public Person(String initialName)
    {
        name = initialName;
    }
    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        newName = "tim";
        name = newName;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void writeOutput()
    {
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
    }
    public boolean hasSameName(Person otherPerson)
    {
        return this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(otherPerson.name);
    }

}
public class Vehicle extends Person {

    String manufactName;
    int engine;



    public Vehicle()
    {
        manufactName = "no name yet";
        engine = 0;
    }
    public Vehicle(String initialManufactName, int initialEngine)
    {
        manufactName = initialManufactName;
        engine = initialEngine;
    }
    public void setManufactName(String newManufactName)
    {
        manufactName = newManufactName;
    }
    public void setEngine(int newEngine)
    {

        engine = newEngine;
    }
    public String getManufactName()
    {

        return manufactName;
    }
    public double getEngine()
    {
        return engine;
    }
    public void writeOutput()
    {
        super.writeOutput();
        System.out.println("Manufacturer: " + manufactName);
        System.out.println("Engine Cyclinders: " + engine);
    }
    public boolean hasSameManufactName(Vehicle otherVehicle)
    {
        return this.manufactName.equalsIgnoreCase(otherVehicle.manufactName);
    }
    public boolean hasSameEngine(Vehicle otherVehicle)
    {
        return this.engine == (otherVehicle.engine);
    }
}

public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    private double load;
    private double towing;

    public Truck()
    {
        load = 0;
        towing = 0;
    }
    public Truck(double initialLoad, double initialTowing)
    {
        load = initialLoad;
        towing = initialTowing;
    }
    public void setLoad(double newLoad)
    {
        load = newLoad;
    }
    public void setTowing(double newTowing)
    {
        towing = newTowing;
    }
    public double getLoad()
    {
        return load;
    }
    public double getTowing()
    {
        return towing;
    }
    public void writeOutput()
    {
        super.writeOutput();
        System.out.println("Load: " + load);
        System.out.println("Towing: " + towing);
    }
    public boolean hasSameLoad(Truck otherTruck)
    {
        return this.load == (otherTruck.load);
    }
    public boolean hasSameTowing(Truck otherTruck)
    {
        return this.towing == (otherTruck.towing);
    }
}

public class Driver extends Truck{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Person p = new Person();
        Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
        Truck t = new Truck();
        t.writeOutput();
    }
```

}

Comment: I'd be concerned by this statement `newName = "tim";` in your `Person`s `setName` method

Comment: oops i forgot to take that out before i posted it. newName = "tim"; is not in the code anymore. I was just trying different things to see what I could get to work

Comment: When posting code, it helps if you can narrow it down to the relevant sections.  It makes your question much more readable, and will get you faster responses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an instance of each class in the hierachy.

Try:

```
Truck t = new Truck();
t.setName("tim");
t.writeOutput();
```

Also, your design is odd: Vehicles wouldn't normally subclass a Person, and a Driver wouldn't normally subclass a Truck. A Driver would be a subclass of a Person. A Truck would be a subclass of a vehicle and a Vehicle would "have" a Driver.

Comment: it works fine if I do it that way but i feel like im not using the inheritance at all if I do it that way. and this is what the question is:

Comment: Create a base class called Vehicle that has the manufacturer’s name (type String), number of cylinders in the engine (type int), and owner (type Person given in Listing 8.1). Then create a class called Truck that is derived from Vehicle and has additional properties: the load capacity in tons (type double, since it may contain a fractional part) and towing capacity in tons (type double). Give your classes a reasonable complement of constructors and accessor methods, and an equals method as well. Write a driver program (no pun intended) that tests all your methods.